# Magento 2: Graphql how to pass productids as parameter (array) in query

Tags: magento2, graphql, parameter

> I'm trying to pass productids in the query but I'm not sure how to
> define it and also need to loop through it, I'm using `for each`
> it's showing SyntaxError.

**I have tried using the productids as `["6", "7"]` or `{"6", "7"}` Query is as below**

```
mutation {
  newRequest(requestParams: [{
      emailId: "askjdhakshd@asdasd.com"
      orderId: "000000023"
      customerId: 0
      product_ids: "[6,7]"
      qty_ordered: 1
      qty_returning: 1
      rma_reason: "Wrong Item Shipped"
      rma_condition: "Open"
      rma_resolution: "Refund"
      delivery_status: "Not Delivered Yet"
      additional_info: ""
      agree_policy: 1
  }]) {
    success_message
  }
}
```

> Query Result is `Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`

**Below are my file changes,**

> **Myvendor\RMAModule\Model\Resolver\RmaRequestResolver.php**

```
<?php

namespace Myvendor\RMAModule\Model\Resolver;
 
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Config\Element\Field;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Exception\GraphQlInputException;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Query\ResolverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Schema\Type\ResolveInfo;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Exception\GraphQlNoSuchEntityException;
use Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Api\AccountManagementInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Exception\GraphQlAuthorizationException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;

class RmaRequestResolver implements ResolverInterface
{
    /**
     * result page Factory
     *
     * @var Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
     */
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http
     */
    protected $request;

    /**
     * @var \Myvendor\RMAModule\Helper\Data
     */
    protected $helper;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\DateTime
     */
    protected $date;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\Session
     */
    protected $customerSession;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface
     */
    protected $url;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseFactory
     */
    protected $responseFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Myvendor\RMAModule\Model\RmaFactory
     */
    protected $rmaFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Myvendor\RMAModule\Model\RmaProductFactory
     */
    protected $rmaProductFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Sales\Model\OrderRepository
     */
    protected $orderRepository;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder
     */
    protected $searchCriteriaBuilder;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request
     * @param \Myvendor\RMAModule\Helper\Data $helper
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\DateTime $date
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
     * @param \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $url
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseFactory $responseFactory
     * @param \Magento\Sales\Model\OrderRepository $orderRepository
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RedirectFactory $resultRedirectFactory
     * @param \Myvendor\RMAModule\Model\RmaFactory $rmaFactory
     * @param \Myvendor\RMAModule\Model\RmaProductFactory $rmaProductFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request,
        \Myvendor\RMAModule\Helper\Data $helper,
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\DateTime $date,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
        \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseFactory $responseFactory,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\OrderRepository $orderRepository,
        \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder,
        \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RedirectFactory $resultRedirectFactory,
        \Myvendor\RMAModule\Model\RmaFactory $rmaFactory,
        \Myvendor\RMAModule\Model\RmaProductFactory $rmaProductFactory
    ) {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->helper = $helper;
        $this->date = $date;
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
        $this->responseFactory = $responseFactory;
        $this->orderRepository = $orderRepository;
        $this->searchCriteriaBuilder = $searchCriteriaBuilder;
        $this->resultRedirectFactory = $resultRedirectFactory;
        $this->rmaFactory = $rmaFactory;
        $this->rmaProductFactory = $rmaProductFactory;
    }

     /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function resolve(
        Field $field,
        $context,
        ResolveInfo $info,
        array $value = null,
        array $args = null)
    {
        $successMessage = [];
        try{
            echo 'called';
            print_r($args['requestParams'][0]);
            
            $productIds = $args['requestParams'][0]["product_ids"];
                        
            foreach ($productIds as $key => $val) {
                print_r($val);
            }

            $successMessage['success_message'] = "You have requested a new Rma Request.";
            return $successMessage;
        } catch (NoSuchEntityException $e) {
            throw new GraphQlNoSuchEntityException(__($e->getMessage()), $e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param array $args
     * @return string
     * @throws GraphQlInputException
     */
    private function getRequestedData(array $args): string
    {
        if (!isset($args['requestParams'][0]['emailId'])) {
            throw new GraphQlInputException(__('EmailId should be specified.'));
        }else if(!isset($args['requestParams'][0]['product_ids'])) {
            throw new GraphQlInputException(__('Product Id should be specified.'));
        }else if(!isset($args['requestParams'][0]['orderId'])) {
            throw new GraphQlInputException(__('Order Id should be specified.'));
        }else if(!isset($args['requestParams'][0]['customerId'])) {
            throw new GraphQlInputException(__('Customer Id should be specified.'));
        }else if(!isset($args['requestParams'][0]['qty_ordered'])) {
            throw new GraphQlInputException(__('Qty Ordered should be specified.'));
        }else if(!isset($args['requestParams'][0]['qty_returning'])) {
            throw new GraphQlInputException(__('Qty Returning should be specified.'));
        }else if(!isset($args['requestParams'][0]['rma_reason'])) {
            throw new GraphQlInputException(__('Rma Reason should be specified.'));
        }else if(!isset($args['requestParams'][0]['rma_condition'])) {
            throw new GraphQlInputException(__('Rma Condition should be specified.'));
        }else if(!isset($args['requestParams'][0]['rma_resolution'])) {
            throw new GraphQlInputException(__('Rma Resolution should be specified.'));
        }else if(!isset($args['requestParams'][0]['delivery_status'])) {
            throw new GraphQlInputException(__('Delivery Status should be specified.'));
        }else if(!isset($args['requestParams'][0]['agree_policy'])) {
            throw new GraphQlInputException(__('Agree Policy should be specified.'));
        }
 
        return $args;
    }

}
```

> **Myvendor\RMAModule\etc\schema.graphqls**

```
type RmaRequestResolver {
    success_message: String @doc(description: "Success Message")
}

input RmaRequestResolverInput {
    emailId: String @doc(description: "Email Address")
    orderId: String @doc(description: "Order Id")
    product_ids: String @doc(description: "Product Ids")
    customerId: Int @doc(description: "Customer Id")
    qty_ordered: Int @doc(description: "Qty Ordered")
    qty_returning: Int @doc(description: "Qty Returning")
    rma_reason: String @doc(description: "Rma Reason")
    rma_condition: String @doc(description: "Rma Condition")
    rma_resolution: String @doc(description: "Rma Resolution")
    delivery_status: String @doc(description: "Delivery Status")
    additional_info: String @doc(description: "Additional Information")
    agree_policy: Int @doc(description: "Agree Policy")
}

type Mutation {
    newRequest(requestParams: [RmaRequestResolverInput]): [RmaRequestResolver] @resolver(class: "Myvendor\\RMAModule\\Model\\Resolver\\RmaRequestResolver") @doc(description:"Request a new Rma")
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Update your Myvendor\RMAModule\etc\schema.graphqls**

```
type Mutation {
    newRequest(requestParams: [RmaRequestResolverInput]): [RmaRequestResolver] @resolver(class: "Myvendor\\RMAModule\\Model\\Resolver\\RmaRequestResolver") @doc(description:"Request a new Rma")
}

input RmaRequestResolverInput {
    emailId: String @doc(description: "Email Address")
    orderId: String @doc(description: "Order Id")
    product_ids: [ItemsIds!]! @doc(description: "Product Ids")
    customerId: Int @doc(description: "Customer Id")
    qty_ordered: Int @doc(description: "Qty Ordered")
    qty_returning: Int @doc(description: "Qty Returning")
    rma_reason: String @doc(description: "Rma Reason")
    rma_condition: String @doc(description: "Rma Condition")
    rma_resolution: String @doc(description: "Rma Resolution")
    delivery_status: String @doc(description: "Delivery Status")
    additional_info: String @doc(description: "Additional Information")
    agree_policy: Int @doc(description: "Agree Policy")
}

input ItemsIds @doc(description: "Defines the product ids") {
    id : Int! @doc(description: "Product Ids")
}

type RmaRequestResolver {
    success_message: String @doc(description: "Success Message")
}
```

> **Reference link :** https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/graphql/mutations/add-products-to-wishlist.html

> **Check Into :** magentoRoot/vendor/magento/module-wishlist-graph-ql

Comment: Thank you for your response. It's working, can you suggest to me any reference link for an image upload through graphql?

Comment: Please ask a new question about it.

Comment: okay i will post a new question